Leaflet - SVGs in Custom Pane not updating position
I am using d3.js to draw svgs on a basic map in Leaflet. I want my custom pane lay on top. I have created a pane and it works just fine.
// draw overlay in custom pane
function drawBorderOverlay() {

    const areaPaths = borderSVGs.selectAll('path')
        .data(topojson.feature(mapInfo, mapInfo.objects.progs).features)
        .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', (d: Feature) => pathG(d))
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none')

    // place svg based on zoom
    const onZoom = () => areaPaths.attr('d', pathG)
    // initialize positioning
    onZoom()
    // reset whenever map is moved
    LMap.on('zoomend ', onZoom)

}



// leaflet setup
function initLeaflet() {

    // initial zoom level
    if (width < 375) initZoomLevel = 9.25
    if (width >= 375 && width < 480) initZoomLevel = 9.5
    if (width > 480 && width < 768) initZoomLevel = 9.75
    if (width >= 768 && width < 1280) initZoomLevel = 10.25
    if (width >= 1280) initZoomLevel = 11

    minZoom.value = initZoomLevel

    // leaflet map setup
    LMap = L.map('map', {
        minZoom: minZoom.value,
        maxZoom: maxZoom,
        scrollWheelZoom: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        zoomSnap: 0.25,
        zoomDelta: 0.25,
        dragging: width < 1280 ? false : true,
        tap: width < 1280 ? false : true,
    }).setView([52.5, 13.4], initZoomLevel);

    zoomLevel.value = LMap.getZoom()

    // Capture the initial bounds of the map
    const initialBounds = LMap.getBounds();
    // Set the maximum bounds to the initial bounds
    LMap.setMaxBounds(initialBounds);

    // Create a MapTiler Layer inside Leaflet
    new L.MaptilerLayer({
        apiKey: "hsl5L4grOcWPCDYacsGF",
        style: "https://api.maptiler.com/maps/f9fd35b5-3026-423b-ac7e-4dc7537efabb/style.json?key=hsl5L4grOcWPCDYacsGF",
    }).addTo(LMap);

    // scale
    L.control.scale({ imperial: false, maxWidth: 150 }).addTo(LMap);

    //initialize svg to add to map
    L.svg().addTo(LMap);

    //Create selection using D3
    const overlay = d3.select(LMap.getPanes().overlayPane)
    const tiles = d3.select(LMap.getPanes().tilePane)
    const svg = overlay.select('svg').attr("pointer-events", "auto")
    fillSVGs = svg.append('g')

    tiles.style('z-index', 5)
    tiles.style('pointer-events', 'none')
    LMap.getPanes().overlayPane.style.zIndex = 4
    LMap.getPanes().mapPane.style.zIndex = 0

    // custom overlay pane for borders
    LMap.createPane('customPane');
    LMap.getPane('customPane').style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // This pane will be clickable
    LMap.getPane('customPane').style.zIndex = 6; // This pane will be above the overlayPane and tilePane
    const customPane = d3.select(LMap.getPanes().customPane);
    const customSVG = customPane.append('svg').attr('class', 'leaflet-zoom-animated').attr('width', '1459px').attr('height', '1200px');
    borderSVGs = customSVG.append('g');

    // Use Leaflets projection API for drawing svg path (creates a stream of projected points)
    const projectPoint = function (this: any, x: number, y: number) {
        const point = LMap.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x))
        this.stream.point(point.x, point.y)
    }

// Use d3's custom geo transform method to implement the above
    const projection = d3.geoTransform({ point: projectPoint })
    // creates geopath from projected points (SVG)
    pathG = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)

    // controls
    document.getElementById('map')?.addEventListener('wheel', () => {
        onZoom()
    })
    document.getElementById('map')?.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {
        onZoom()
    })

    showData(data2020)
    drawBorderOverlay()
}

However, when zoomed-in and I pan the map the area, which was outside the map view before, is not re-drawn on the custom pane and remains empty. I was assuming that the custom pane behaves the same as the built-in panes and updates the position according to movement.
Obviously the svg in the custom pane is missing the correct view box and translate attribution (compared with the svg in the overlay pane):
dom
Resulting in incomplete information in the view after panning:
Borders in red are only drawn where the "old" view was
What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!
